# Javascript regular expressions for a text input

Tags: javascript

I need to do a text input validation in javascript with the below rules.

Could you please let me know the regular expression for this?

the Text Input should be exactly 8 long, and it should meet the following conditions:

Starts with 3 letters
Then and Underscore and ends with 4 Digits
I have tried this : /^[a-z A-Z]{3} - [0-9]{4} *$/ but it did not work Thank you

Comment: While @PeterNoges has already answered your question, there many online tools out there which help you build regexp easily, such as this [one](https://regexr.com).

Answer (score 1):

do these work?
One is underscore, one is hyphen based. Typed from my phone.

var match = yourStringVariable.match(/(^[a-z A-Z]{3} - [0-9]{4})/i);

var match = yourStringVariable.match(/(^[a-z A-Z]{3}_[0-9]{4})/i);